# how to compare a column in first dataframe with a column in second dataframe, and extract values from another column in second dataframe upon matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have a dataframe:

```
a = [['A','def'],['A','xyz'],['A','uiu'], ['B','jkl'], ['C','pqr'], ['C','rty']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['1', '2'])

    1   2
0   A   def
1   A   xyz
2   A   uiu
3   B   jkl
4   C   pqr
5   C   rty
```

and another dataframe:

```
a = [['A'], ['B'], ['C'],['D']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['1'])



    1
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
```

I want to compare column "1" in df2 with column "1" in df1, and if they match, I want to have a resulting dataframe that will contain values of column "2" joined with "|" (if there are multiple matches).
For example, the result of above two dataframes should look like this:

```
    1   2
0   A   def|xyz|uiu
1   B   jkl
2   C   pqr|rty
3   D   NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with aggregate `join`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='1').groupby('1')['2'].agg('|'.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   1            2
0  A  def|xyz|uiu
1  B          jkl
2  C      pqr|rty
```

EDIT: For add alo not matched values is use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for alwyas unique values of column `1` and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add missing values:

```
df22 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['1'])
df = (df1.merge(df22, on='1')
         .groupby('1')['2']
         .agg('|'.join)
         .reindex(df22['1'])
         .reset_index())
print (df)
   1            2
0  A  def|xyz|uiu
1  B          jkl
2  C      pqr|rty
3  D          NaN
```

Comment: what if a value doesn't match? Let me edit the question, so you can make changes in your answer.

Comment: @SaadZaheer - If no match then not exist in ouput.

Comment: requires no changes to solution?

Comment: @SaadZaheer - yes, give me some time.